# PlacePicker location show on Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, android-maps

I got the user current location using place picker API. Now I want to show the user selected location in my activity. Below is my code:

```
public class StoreFinder extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

Context context;
private final static int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 999;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private boolean wifi, mobileData;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
String placeAddress, placeName;
LatLng toLatLng;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location_finder);
    context = StoreFinder.this;
    wifi = Utils.WifiEnable(context);
    mobileData = Utils.isMobileDataEnable(context);
    /* declaration of map client */
         mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .build();
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    try {
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(StoreFinder.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
// open map

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
  data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
        placeName = String.format("%s", place.getName());
        String latitude = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().latitude);
        String longitude = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().longitude);
        placeAddress = String.format("%s", place.getAddress());
        toLatLng = place.getLatLng();
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new 
              MarkerOptions().position(toLatLng)
              .title(placeName).snippet(placeAddress)
             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_location)));
         mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(toLatLng,11));
```

It's working fine with the place picker. When I add marker the activity crash with null pointer exception.

I follow [place picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102425/how-to-show-placepicker-location-on-a-google-map) link.

below is the error

```
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: What's the error, and where? How is `mMap` initialized?

Comment: i have update my code

Comment: I still don't see mMap being initialized.

Comment: I define that line in my onCreate method and that line crash my activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the Map. Assuming your Activity layout has a map fragment, something like this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

On the onCreate of your app you need to:

```
// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

And you need to implement the method onMapReady as:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
}
```

This way your defining the mMap object that was NULL on your crash report.

Comment: And how can I get the user current location marker onMapReady ??

Comment: Getting the current location is another task. With this you initialize the map, to get user current location refer to this: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current

Comment: there is no way to show the place picker latlang values on MapReady method??

Comment: The problem is that maybe the location is not yet obtained when the map is ready.

Comment: To show the placePicker lat/lng use the same code your already have in the onActivityResult. Your map should already be initialized in the onCreate as I told you to and you will no longer have the null pointer exception

Comment: yes, it's work. but doesn't show me any marker on the map